# I have a problem making a request to the StarWars API

Tags: reactjs

I am a person who is learning to use APIs with react and i have a problem because my code does not work. I get the following error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')  App.jsx:24
.However I have optional chaining applied.
I show you my code and I hope you can help me

useFetch.js

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const useFetch = url => {

    const [response, setResponse] = useState()

    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(res=>setResponse(res.data))
        .catch(err=> console.log(err.message))
    }, [])

    return response

}

export default useFetch
```

App.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import FormInput from './components/FormInput'
import Residents from './components/Residents'

function App() {

  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState()
  const [response, setResponse] = useState()

  const number = parseInt(response)

  const updatePage = number => {
    const URL = `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/${number}/`
    axios.get(URL)
      .then(res => setPlanets(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const URL = `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/${number}/`
    axios.get(URL)
      .then(res => updatePage())
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }, [])

  console.log(number)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormInput
        setResponse={setResponse}
      />
      <hr />
      {
        planets?.residents.map(resident => (
          <Residents
            resident={resident}
            key={resident.name}

          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Residents.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import useFetch from '../hooks/useFetch'

const Residents = ({ resident }) => {

          const users = useFetch(resident)


          console.log(users)
   
  return (
    <article>
        

    </article>
  )
}

export default Residents
```

Comment: If `planets.residents` is `undefined` then what is `planets`?  As a basic initial debugging step, log its value to the console to see what it actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your residents is not an array. Make it array first or something you are storing in resident is not a object and map() method only works on array not on object. So fix it.

```js
planets?.residents?.map()
```

use "?" after residents and your residents is not an array. So you need to make it array or whatever you are storing in you residents variable is not an array please cross check you variable/state.

Comment: I have corrected the App.jsx code. However, it still throws me the following error. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
App.jsx:25 Request failed with status code 404.  You could help me.

Comment: Share sandbox link with your code. Hope till now you finded the solution.

Comment: Hello here I send you the link of the sandbox with all the code. The problem I have is that in line 10 of App.jsx response it comes up as undefined and I can't assign it to line 11.

https://codesandbox.io/s/white-shape-2rnciv?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: Because your number is empty.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix that error? Thank you

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-axios-9ijh6s?file=/src/App.jsx

here is link solved.

  // For more help
  // Youtube: bugslogger
  // Discord: https://discord.gg/twGG3zeXQM
  // Github: Bugslogger

Comment: I now join the discord group called Bugslogger. I want to know what is your nickname there because I have some errors in one of my personal projects and I need to solve it.